# JQuery click-function for each link does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a "collapse all"-button for Bootstrap 3 collapsible plugin. It seems to work fine, but only if I have got only one single collapsible on my page. When I add another one, my method will still just work in the first link item.

Here ist my JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#toggle-all").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $hidden = $(this).parent().data("hidden");

        if ($hidden == "false") {
            $(this).parent().find(".collapse.in").each(function () {
                $(this).collapse("hide");
            });
            $(this).parent().data("hidden", "true");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".collapse").not(".in").each(function () {
                $(this).collapse("show");
            });
            $(this).parent().data("hidden", "false");
        }

        $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
    });
});
```

And here a fiddle to try: **http://jsfiddle.net/rMdLZ/**

Any ideas why it does not work as expected?

Thanks,
Julian

Comment: That's because IDs MUST be unique on document context...

Comment: possible duplicate of [wrapAll() only working on the first element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605141/wrapall-only-working-on-the-first-element)

Comment: there is a css class *btn-primary*, subscribing click to it makes all working,instead id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using 2 id's. Id's must be unique elements on each document.

See this SE question for reference: [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Change it to Classes:

```
$(function () {
  $(".toggle-all").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $hidden = $(this).parent().data("hidden");

    if ($hidden == "false") {
        $(this).parent().find(".collapse.in").each(function () {
            $(this).collapse("hide");
        });
        $(this).parent().data("hidden", "true");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find(".collapse").not(".in").each(function () {
            $(this).collapse("show");
        });
        $(this).parent().data("hidden", "false");
    }

    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vP4e9/1/

Comment: Not page but document. Page can contain iframes ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, sometimes I do not see the wood for the trees. Now it works perfectly :-)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `ids`. Use classes and I think you should do fine.

### Why?

Because the ids have to be unique through out the frame.

`$('#someId')` will always return you the same element, but `$('.someClass')` will return you all elements with `someClass` class

I've changed  `$("#toggle-all").click` to  `$(".toggle-all").click` and added the `toggle-all` class the the collapse all buttons. And it works fine.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rMdLZ/5/)